# Adding dotted lines indicating the hierarchical structure in a bullet list in Microsoft Word

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

Is there any way to add dotted lines (or any other visual indicator) indicating the hierarchical structure in a bullet list in Microsoft Word?

E.g. like some file browsers show:

[image]

(I don't want any icon, just text + dotted lines any other visual indicator showing the hierarchical structure)

I use Microsoft Word 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Does [Create a hierarchy](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-a-hierarchy-45b915d6-eef0-4722-a7ac-b42f1ffe7c3c) help?

Comment: You might also be able to do something using the [Organization Chart Tool](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_the_organization_chart_tool.html)